# Dagger 2 fragments with different scope

Tags: android, dagger-2, named-scope

Is it possible to have two fragments from different scope in same activity where activity is in same scope as one of the fragments. I wrote sample code here (https://github.com/damirmiljkovic/daggerimplementation) which you can check it out.

What I am trying to achieve is to have single activity with multiple fragments, login fragment and user fragment. I have identity url for user authentication and after user is successfully authenticated API will return base URL for rest of the APIs. Now I have 2 retrofit instances, one is created on application creation and second one is created after user logs in. So activity and login fragment are within one scope(let's say @Singelton) and user fragment is with in other scope(let's say @UserScope). I need to get user details from API right after user logs in and if some conditions are not met I open user fragment so user can fill missing details.

Comment: Possible? Yes, but not with `dagger.android`. Feasible? Probably not. It would help if you could communicate what you're trying to achieve, because there is probably a better solution than a Fragment & Activity scoped component

Comment: @DavidMedenjak I amended my question with what I am trying to achieve.